# Failed to resize Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, sku

I have a Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets with 10 instances. Since we are migrating from Intel SKU to AMD SKU, I resize my VMSS's CPU size from *Standard_DS2_v2* to *Standard_E4-2as_v4*. After successfully upgrate, the size of VMSS is shown as *Standard_E4-2as_v4*. However, the instance still shows *Standard_DS2_v2* and from subscription quota I can see the used SKU is still the *Standard_DS2_v2*. Seems the migration of SKU failed. How to resize VMSS? Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could update to the latest, then the instance will be restart and change to target VM size. You can click the **Upgrade** button from each scale set instance panel. After a while, go back to the Virtual machine scale set panel then review the instance panel again, you will see the updated size.

[image]

Or you can use PowerShell commands to manage it. This command starts an upgrade of the VMSS named VMScaleSet001 that has the instance ID of 0.

```
Update-AzVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName "Group011" -VMScaleSetName "VMScaleSet001" -InstanceId "0"
```